# problem of django form in posting request

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on a project and I made a form but when I submit sth it doesn't send it to database although in cmd it shows that request method is post.I really don'tkhow how to deal with it.
thats template code:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}
<title>projects</title>
{%endblock title%}
{%block content%}
<div class="container">
</br>
 <form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="project" placeholder="new project?">
</div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
</form>
    </br>
    </br>




   <table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
   <tr>
       <th scope="col"> project-title</th>
       <th scope="col">update</th>
       <th scope="col">delete</th>
       <th scope="col">divide</th>


   </tr>
   </thead>

    <tbody>

{% for obj in all_projects %}

    <tr>
      <td>{{ obj.proTitle }}</td>
      <td>{{ obj.done }}</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
      <td>Devide</td>
    </tr>


    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
</table>


</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

any advise will be greatly appreciated:))

Comment: please include your `views.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it ;
in the input tag  i put name="project" but the attribute that I defined in my model was "proTitle"
so when I chnged it the problem solved.